# Angular directive imported but not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular version 7.3.7. I created a directive and it's not working properly. Example of directive:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[matchHeight]'
})
export class MatchHeightDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("this will be work", "color: red");
  }

}
```

And importing my directive on `shared.module.ts`.

```
import { MatchHeightDirective } from './directives/match-height.directive';

const pipes = [DateFormatPipe, SecondToTime, HighlightSearch, TimeFormatPipe];
const components = [
  MatchHeightDirective,
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [pipes, components],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [DraggableService],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    components,
  ],
})
export class QmsSharedModule {}
```

And using it like:

```
<div class="row" matchHeight></div>
```

But result are nothing works. What am i doing wrong ? Any advice for this ?

Answer (score 2):

`declarations: [pipes, components],`

As pipes and components are already arrays, so your declaration is now an array with 2 arrays inside it.

You can modify it to:

`declarations: [...pipes, ...components],`

and it should work.

Comment: And also your `exports: [CommonModule, ...components]`

Comment: If this doesn't work, probably put a stackblitz to be able to take a look on what else might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take your pipes and directives out of their arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Also export pipes, directives and components to shared module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...COMPONENTS, ...PIPES, ...DIRECTIVES],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],

  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  exports: [CommonModule, ...COMPONENTS, ...PIPES, ...DIRECTIVES]
})
```

And change the styling for verification

```
export class MatchHeightDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.color = 'red';
  }
```

Component.html

```
<p matchHeight>Color change </p>
```